# How can I show a message result for inserting data according to a condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I show a message according to the trigger result?

I have this trigger; that is I can only insert a new message between two users if they were matched before, so I check these ID's that I inserted if they exist in the `Match` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_SentMessage_Insteadof
ON messages
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM inserted, matchs AS m
    WHERE (inserted.sentFrom = m.userID1 AND inserted.sentTo = m.userID2)
       OR (inserted.sentFrom = m.userID2 AND inserted.sentTo = m.userID1)
END
```

I know the `*` in select is not correct but I don't know how to replace it with a message.

For example this line:

```
insert into messages 
values ('2017-05-01T13:45:03', 'heey', '201827364','124234524')
```

should return the answer "This message can't be sent".

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what you are asking correctly but as far as i can see it should be something like

```
create TRIGGER trg_SentMessage_Insteadof
ON messages
Instead OF INSERT
AS 
Begin
   declare @result varchar(30)
   if(exists( SELECT *
         FROM    inserted,matchs as m
          WHERE ( inserted.sentFrom=m.userID1 and inserted.sentTo=m.userID2 ) or 
          (inserted.sentFrom=m.userID2 and inserted.sentTo=m.userID1)))
       BEGIN
        //Your insert statement 
         set @result = 'inserted Successfull'
         select @result as Result
       END
   else
       set @result = 'Cannot be inserted'
       select @result as Result
END
```

Comment: Thank you  , but i get the 'Command(s) completed successfully.' on messages screen , shouldn't be 'inserted Successfuly' or 'Cannot be inserted' ?

Comment: you have to execute the trigger just insert  a new column

Comment: yes , my bad i executed it incorrectly , thank you so much!

Comment: after checking i see that the table is not being updated -added after inserting(but it shows that inserted successfuly)

Comment: if i  put the insert statement  in the trigger  i excute the trigger and then **again i excute only the insert statement** it will add to table correctly , put if i delete the insert statement from the trigger and excute it without the insert statement  , then excute the insert statement alone it doesn't add , in both cases it shows the correct result msg :\

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use trigger for this requirement ?

To insert records into your table you can write a stored procedure and pass parameters to that as per your table structure. And, you can check the values in the tables before inserting and if your condition satisfies then let it insert else do not.

You can edit the below procedure as per your logic:

```
Create procedure InsertSentMessageCheck
@col1 datatype1,
@col2 datatype2,
@col3 datatype3,
@col4 datatype4
As
Begin

Declare @counter int = 0

select @counter=count(*) from matches where (@col1=userid1 and @col2=userid2) or (@col1=userid2 and @col2=userid1)
if @counter>0 
begin
--<your insert statement>
select 'Iserted Successfully'
end
else
select 'Can not be inserted'

end
```

Comment: thank you , but i was trying to do it as a trigger , it's not possible?